# Using dictionary keys as field name in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

So, I want to make a single report in `C#`.

First I load the data using `LINQ`:

```
 var query = (from c in customer
                where c.id.Equals(customer_id)
                orderby c.id
                select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I make the `dictionary` contain the field name in the database and a label.

```
 Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            list.Add("name", "Full Name");
            list.Add("address", "Address");
            list.Add("phone", "Customer Phone");
            list.Add("email", "Customer Email");
```

Basically I want to iterate the whole `dictionary` and using the `key` as a field name identifier:

```
foreach (var pair in list)
            {
                graphic.DrawString(pair.Value, font, brush, startX, startY + offset);
                graphic.DrawString(":", font, brush, semicolonPos, startY + offset);
                graphic.DrawString(query.[pair.Key], font, brush, semicolonPos, startY + offset); // This is not working, any suggestion?
                offset += 40;
            }
```

So my question is, is it possible to have something like `**query.[pair.Key]**`, or do you have any suggestions for this case?

I am basically a `PHP` programmer, so maybe my mindset is still on web programming :D. And sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: Just one question - why are you drawing items manually? Is it requirement? You can use some control like PropertyGrid for displaying all object's properties and values

Comment: What is `customer`? Is it a LINQ to SQL table? Entity Framework table? In-memory list? Something else?

Comment: Your logic is totally off here. I think you are trying to get specific fields is the customer class, however the way you have it is not going to work with the query collection. you probably want to tell us what you are trying to achieve and we can suggest the rout to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var pair in list)
{
    graphic.DrawString(pair.Value, font, brush, startX, startY + offset);
    graphic.DrawString(":", font, brush, semicolonPos, startY + offset);  

    var pi=typeof(Customer).GetProperty(pair.key);
    var val= pi.GetValue(query,null);
    graphic.DrawString(val, font, brush, semicolonPos, startY + offset);
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is close for my solution. But it got exception "Object does not match target type" at line **var val**.

Comment: Please check `query` is null and Your pair.key value equal object property name.

Comment: So I change my query to .ToList(), Instead of .FirstOrDefault();. When I check query.Count() its returning "1". The value of **pi** I think its already right, on the first iteration it show "System.string name"

Comment: for example your query.name value is empty, pi.GetValue(query,"name") returns null. You must check val is null like this `if(val!=null){ graphic.Draw...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pair.Key instead of query.[pair.Key]

```
 graphic.DrawString(pair.Key , font, brush, semicolonPos, startY + offset);query.[pair.Key]
```

Comment: For example, my first key in dictionary is "name". So in my iteration, I want to make query.[pair.Key] acting like query.name

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do isn't particularly best practise because it's using magic strings to try and access the property values of your customer object. You also don't have any separation of concerns - the view is mixed with data access etc.

You haven't shown what type the 'customer' variable is, but ideally you would have a `Customer` type and then your 'view' would access the properties in a strongly typed manner. I can add an example if you describe what UI technology you're using.

Comment: I'm using winform for this case, and yes the type is Customer

Comment: Well you could use reflection as ebattulga shows, but I really would rethink the approach. What advantage are you getting from the dictionary of property names? Surely the Customer type doesn't change regularly? Why not just use query.Name etc. directly in the rendering code?

Comment: That will be my last approach, because actually i have a lot of field :D. I need to doing this, because several field need to be manipulated before It shown